# MongoDb Java Driver toJson() and $oid

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, objectid

I'm building a Java Jersey API which uses MongoDb and MongoDb driver.

The resources should output JSON of the stored MongoDb document to be used in the frontend project using Svelte.

Due to the standard `org.bson.Document.toJson()` implementation the output of my documents look somehow like:

```
[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5e97f08f2175aa9174dbec0e" }, "hour" : 8, "minute" : 15, "enabled" : true, "duration" : 120 }
```

I would rather like it to be:

```
[{ "_id" : "5e97f08f2175aa9174dbec0e", "hour" : 8, "minute" : 15, "enabled" : true, "duration" : 120 }
```

That way it's easier to handle the id in the frontend. So how to get rid of the $oid object?

I already managed to get the format as I wish by using:

```
JsonWriterSettings settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder()
                .outputMode(JsonMode.RELAXED)
                .objectIdConverter((value, writer) -> writer.writeString(value.toHexString()))
                .build();
        System.out.println(doc.toJson(settings));
```

But how to register this setting object globally so that every `doc.toJson()` call will use it?

And what will happen if I send modified or new documents from the frontend to the API and do:

```
Document document = Document.parse(doc);
```

Is my modified `_id` field automatically converted again to an ObjectId? Or do I need a org.bson.codecs.Decoder or CodecRegistry? How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

$oid refers to ObjectId field type in [bson spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html). As far as I know, you need to manipulate your document to replace ObjectId for your _id into String.

```
String oidAsString = document.getObjectId("_id").toString();
document.put("_id", oidAsString);
```